# GTK3 &Python interactive - architecture of classes - PopupMenu Of GTK3 on matplotlib Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, gtk, popupmenu

I am using Python & GTK3 under mac OS X Sierra in order to display a database of nodes as a Diagram. It is a MVP architecture.

I use matplotlib to display my figure. As my display is interactive so I have to receive signals. I decided to receive signals directly from my matplotlib canvas instead using GTK GUI, as GTK event do not have enough parameters. Actually I want to receive signals on my canvas using matplotlib and show a popup menu of GTK.

The function that you have to look is MainFigurePressed. The idea is I received signals on my canvas with the program DrawChronoMap using the function Detecte() than I popup a menu of my GTK GUI calling View by connecting Viewhandlers. In order to launch my program, my controller will call my view.I am wondering how can I pass in argument my class Viewhandler in my class DrawChronoMap?

How should I do? How should I change my architecture to do that?

I have three classes actually :

class View():

```
def __init__(self, MainController):

    #set windows
    self.window = Gtk.Window()
    self.window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    self.window.set_default_size(10000, 10000)
    self.window.set_title('ChronoMap')

    #Init Glade file # Get windows from glade
    self.interface = Gtk.Builder()
    self.interface.add_from_file("interface1.glade")
    self.mainWindow = self.interface.get_object("mainWindow")
    self.aboutchronomap = self.interface.get_object("aboutchronomap")
    self.fichierdialogue=self.interface.get_object("fichierdialogue")
    self.sw=self.interface.get_object("mainFigure")
    self.toolbar=self.interface.get_object("MatplotlibToolbar")
    self.sw3=self.interface.get_object("scrolledwindow1")
    self.sw4=self.interface.get_object("scrolledwindow2")
    self.add_node_window=self.interface.get_object("add_node_window")
    self.add_edge_window=self.interface.get_object("add_edge_window")
    self.modify_edge_window=self.interface.get_object("modify_edge_window")
    self.modify_node_window=self.interface.get_object("modify_node_window")
    self.add_reference_node_edge=self.interface.get_object("add_reference_node_edge")
    self.popupmenuCartoNode=self.interface.get_object("popupmenuCartoNode")
    self.popupmenuCartoEdge=self.interface.get_object("popupmenuCartoEdge")
    self.popupmenuCartoOtherplace=self.interface.get_object("popupmenuCartoOtherplace")

    self.popupmenuChronoNode=self.interface.get_object("popupmenuChronoNode")
    self.popupmenuChronoZoneBC=self.interface.get_object("popupmenuChronoZoneBC")
    self.popupmenuChronoCursor=self.interface.get_object("popupmenuChronoCursor")




    #Global controller
    self.controller=MainController

    #Init CartoCanvas
    self.figCarto = Figure(figsize=(20,20), dpi=80)
    self.axCarto = self.figCarto.add_subplot(111)
    self.canvasCarto = FigureCanvas(self.figCarto)

    # Init ChronoCanvas
    self.figChrono = Figure(figsize=(20,20), dpi=80)
    self.axChrono = self.figChrono.add_subplot(111)
    self.canvasChrono = FigureCanvas(self.figChrono)

    #Create a New graph on the controller
    self.controller.create_new_graph("CartoChronomap")

    #add node & edges
    nodeA=self.controller.create_evenement("outdated research material", "01-01-2016 00:00:00", "01-02-2016 00:00:00", 1, "BLAH BLAH BLAH", "http://")
    nodeB= self.controller.create_evenement("Projected tsunami frequency too low", "08-08-2016 00:00:00", "09-10-2016 00:00:00", 1, "OK", "http://")
    nodeC=self.controller.create_evenement("EV C", "08-07-2016 00:00:00", "09-08-2016 00:00:00", 1, "HOOOOO", "http://")
    nodeD=self.controller.create_evenement("Accident", "08-10-2016 00:00:00", "09-11-2016 00:00:00", 1, "HOOOOO", "http://")



    self.controller.create_edge(nodeA,nodeB, "LeLien", "Une mega explosion", "[]")
    self.controller.create_edge(nodeB,nodeA, "InverseLien", "Une giga explosion", "[]")
    self.controller.create_edge(nodeC,nodeD, "LienTest", "Ceci est un lien test", "[]")
    self.controller.calculate_position('spring_layout');


    #Connect to draw chronograph
    self.FdessinChrono=Draw_chrono.DrawChronoMap(self.axChrono,self.controller)       
    #Connect to draw Cartograph
    self.FdessinCarto = Draw_cartograph.DrawCartoMap(self.axCarto, self.controller)        

    #draw
    self.FdessinCarto.draw_cartograph()
    self.FdessinChrono.draw_chronograph()

    #MouseFunction Carto
    self.FdessinCarto.zoom_wheel()
    self.FdessinCarto.pan_drag()
    #self.FdessinCarto.drag_node()
    self.FdessinCarto.ChangeNodeColor()
    self.FdessinCarto.node_popup_mouse_over()
    self.FdessinCarto.edge_popup_mouse_over()

    #Global carto event & chrono event
    self.CartoEvent = self.FdessinCarto.Detect()
    self.ChronoEvent = self.FdessinChrono.Detect() 

    print(self.CartoEvent,self.ChronoEvent)

    #MouseFunction Chrono
    self.FdessinChrono.cursor()
    self.FdessinChrono.ChangeColor()
    #self.FdessinChrono.pan_drag()
    self.FdessinChrono.node_popup_mouse_over()


    #Display Mode
    self.display_Mode = None




    #Creating the ListStore model
    #node_liststore
    self.node_liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, str,str,str,str)

    if len(self.FdessinCarto.pos) != 0:
        for i,node in enumerate(self.FdessinCarto.pos):
            self.node_liststore.append([str(node.title),str(node.start_time),str(node.end_time),str(node.node_group),str(node.description),str(node.attachment_list)])

    #edge_liststore
    self.edge_liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, str,str,str)

    if len(self.FdessinCarto.edgelist) !=0:
        edge_prop=self.FdessinCarto.controller.edge_data(nodeA,nodeB)
        edge_prop1=self.FdessinCarto.controller.edge_data(nodeB,nodeA)
        self.edge_liststore.append([edge_prop['label'],str(nodeA.title),str(nodeB.title),edge_prop['description'],edge_prop['attachment_list']])
        self.edge_liststore.append([edge_prop1['label'],str(nodeA.title),str(nodeB.title),edge_prop1['description'],edge_prop1['attachment_list']])


    #creating the filtre
    self.node_filter = self.node_liststore.filter_new()
    self.edge_filter = self.edge_liststore.filter_new()

    #setting the filter function, note that we're not using the
    self.node_filter.set_visible_func(ViewHandler.node_filter_func)
    self.edge_filter.set_visible_func(ViewHandler.edge_filter_func)

    #creating the treeview for Node, making it use the filter as a model, and adding the columns
    self.treeviewNode = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.node_liststore)
    for i, column_title in enumerate(["Nom", "Date début", "Date fin", "Type de noeud", "Description du noeud","fichier"]):
        self.Noderenderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.Noderenderer.set_property("editable", True)
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, self.Noderenderer, text=i)
        self.treeviewNode.append_column(column)
        #self.Noderenderer.connect("edited", self.onButtonCreateNode)


    #creating the treeview for edge
    self.treeviewEdge = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.edge_liststore)
    for i, column_title in enumerate(["Nom", "Noeud 1", "Noeud 2", "Description du lien","fichier"]):
        self.Edgerenderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.Edgerenderer.set_property("editable", True)
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, self.Edgerenderer, text=i)
        self.treeviewEdge.append_column(column)

    # Connect with signals
    self.interface.connect_signals(ViewHandler(self))

    #setting up the layout, putting the treeview in a scrollwindow
    self.sw3.add(self.treeviewNode)
    self.sw4.add(self.treeviewEdge)
    self.sw3.show_all()
    self.sw4.show_all()
    self.window.add(self.sw)
    self.sw.show_all()
    # All ready - open interface
    Gtk.main()

def update_data(self):
    self.CartoEvent = self.FdessinCarto.Detect()
    self.ChronoEvent = self.FdessinChrono.Detect() 

    print(self.CartoEvent,self.ChronoEvent)
```

class ViewHandler():

```
def __init__(self, ViewConnection):
    self.View = ViewConnection


def resetplot(self):
    axCarto.cla()
    axCarto.set_xlim(0,10)
    axCarto.set_ylim(0,10)
    axCarto.grid(True)

    axChrono.cla()
    axChrono.set_xlim(0,10)
    axChrono.set_ylim(0,10)
    axChrono.grid(True)


# All button signals of GTK

#Signal to open windows "creation of node"
def create_node_button_press_event(self,widget):
    self.View.add_node_window.show_all()


#Signal to open window "creation of link"
def create_link_button_press_event(self,widget):
    self.View.add_edge_window.show_all()

def onButtonCreateNode(self,widget):
    self.resetplot()
    nom=self.View.interface.get_object('name_node1').get_text()
    node_type=self.View.interface.get_object('node_type1').get_text()
    start_time_node=self.View.interface.get_object('start_time_node1').get_text()
    end_time_node=self.View.interface.get_object('end_time_node1').get_text()
    #print(nom,node_type,start_time_node,end_time_node)

    self.View.node_liststore.append([nom, start_time_node, end_time_node, node_type, "BLAH BLAH BLAH", "http://"])
    self.View.FdessinCarto.controller.create_evenement(nom, start_time_node, end_time_node, node_type, "BLAH BLAH BLAH", "http://")
    self.View.FdessinChrono.controller.create_evenement(nom, start_time_node, end_time_node, node_type, "BLAH BLAH BLAH", "http://")
    self.View.canvasCarto.draw()
    self.View.canvasChrono.draw()

    self.View.add_node_window.destroy()
    self.View.sw.show_all()
    self.View.sw3.show_all()


def onButtonAddFileEdge(self,widget):
    pass

def onButtonCreateEdge(self,widget):
    nom=self.View.interface.get_object('name_edge2').get_text()
    edge_description=self.View.interface.get_object('edge_type2').get_text()
    node1_edge=self.View.interface.get_object('node1_edge_entry').get_text()
    node2_edge=self.View.interface.get_object('node2_edge_entry2').get_text()


    #create signal with liststore
    self.View.edge_liststore.append([node1_edge,node2_edge, nom, edge_description, "[]"])
    #create link with canvas
    self.View.FdessinCarto.controller.create_edge(node1_edge,node2_edge, nom, edge_description, "[]")
    self.View.FdessinChrono.controller.create_edge(node1_edge,node2_edge, nom, edge_description, "[]")
    self.View.canvasCarto.draw()
    self.View.canvasChrono.draw()

    #register it in the treeStore
    edge_prop=list(self.View.FdessinCarto.controller.edge_data(node1_edge,node2_edge))

    self.View.sw.show_all()
    self.View.add_edge_window.destroy()


#Signal to contextual menu
def onMainFigurePressed(self,widget,event):
    print(event.type, event.button, event.window, event.x, event.y, event.time,event.get_state(),event.time)

    #update event 
    self.View.update_data()

    self.CartoEvent = self.View.FdessinCarto.Detect()
    self.ChronoEvent = self.View.FdessinChrono.Detect() 

    print(self.View.CartoEvent,self.View.ChronoEvent,self.CartoEvent,self.ChronoEvent)

    if event.type == Gdk.EventType.ENTER_NOTIFY:
        print("yes, enter")
    if event.type == Gdk.EventType.LEAVE_NOTIFY:
                print("No, out")            


    if event.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS and event.button == 3:
        if self.display_Mode == "carto" :
            print("oui, carto " )
            self.View.popupmenuCartoNode.popup(None, None, None, None, event.button, event.time)
        elif self.display_Mode == "chrono" :
            print( "oui chrono")
            self.View.popupmenuChronoNode.popup(None, None, None, None, event.button, event.time)

    else:
        return None

def onButtonModifyNode(self,widget,event):
    #print("modify windows show all")
    self.View.modify_node_window.show_all()


def onButtonDeleteNode(self,widget,event):
    #print("button pressed delete")
    self.View.FdessinCarto.deleteNode()

def onButtonLinkNode(self,widget,event):
    #print("hello")
    self.View.add_edge_window.show_all()

def onButtonCopyNode(self,widget,event):
    #print("copy")
    self.View.FdessinCarto.copynode()
    #print("copy it")

def onButtonOtherplaceCreateNode(self,widget,event):
    self.View.add_node_window.show_all()

def onButtonAttributsNode(self,widget,event):
    self.View.FdessinCarto.display_node_attributs()

#Signal of menubars
def on_node_file_button_press_event(self,widget):
    self.View.add_node_window.show_all()

def on_create_edge_button_press_event(self,widget):
    self.View.add_edge_window.show_all()

def on_Open_button_press_event(self,widget,event):
    self.View.fichierdialogue.show_all()

 #signal of about
def on_gtk_about_button_release_event(self,widget,event):
    self.View.aboutchronomap.show_all()


# close window
def on_close_button_press_event(self,widget,event):
    self.View.on_quit_button_press_event (widget,event)

def on_quit_button_press_event (self,widget,event):
#pop up menu
    dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(None, 0, Gtk.MessageType.INFO,Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL, "Vous partez?")
    dialog.format_secondary_text("Voulez vous toujours partir?")
    response=dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        Gtk.main_quit()
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        dialog.destroy()
    dialog.destroy()
    return True

def on_confirmation_deletenode_button_press_event (self,widget,event):
    #pop up menu
        dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(None, 0, Gtk.MessageType.INFO,Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL, "Suppression du noeud?")
        dialog.format_secondary_text("Voulez vous vraiment supprimer le noeud?")
        response=dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            Gtk.main_quit()
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            dialog.destroy()
        dialog.destroy()
        return True

def on_mainWindow_destroy(self, widget):
    Gtk.main_quit()

def on_carto_display_button_press_event(self,widget,event):
    self.display_Mode = "carto"

    child=self.View.sw.get_child()
    child1 = self.View.toolbar.get_child()
    #print(child)

    if child != None:
        self.View.toolbar.remove(child1)
        self.View.sw.remove(child)
        self.box.remove(self.View.canvasChrono)

    self.box=Gtk.Box()
    self.View.sw.add(self.box)
    self.box.pack_start(self.View.canvasCarto, True, True, 0)
    #Add toolbar
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.View.canvasCarto, self.View.window)
    self.View.toolbar.add_with_viewport(toolbar)          

    self.View.sw.show_all()

def on_chrono_display_button_press_event(self,widget,event):
    self.display_Mode= "chrono"

    child = self.View.sw.get_child()
    child1 = self.View.toolbar.get_child()

    if child != None:
        self.View.toolbar.remove(child1)
        self.View.sw.remove(child)
        self.box.remove(self.View.canvasCarto)


    self.View.FdessinChrono.draw_chronograph()

    self.box=Gtk.Box()
    self.View.sw.add(self.box)
    self.box.pack_start(self.View.canvasChrono, True, True, 0)


    #Add toolbar
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.View.canvasChrono, self.View.window)
    self.View.toolbar.add_with_viewport(toolbar)        

    self.View.sw.show_all()
```

class DrawChronoMap:

```
def __init__(self,ax, controller): 
    #Global controller
    self.controller = controller

    #Global graph
    self.G = self.controller.total_graph()

    #Global model
    self.model=self.controller.model

    #Global Axis
    self.ax = ax

    #Global figure
    self.fig = self.ax.get_figure()

    #Gloal canvas
    self.canvas = self.ax.get_figure().canvas  

    #Global list

    self.nodelist = self.controller.get_node_list()
    self.edgelist=self.controller.get_edge_list()

    #Global empty collection
    #Global nodecollection
    self.nodecollection=None

    #Gloabl datanode
    self.datanode = []         

    #Global empty list
    self.eventnode_with_rectangle=[]
    self.start_date=[]
    self.end_date=[]
    self.event_name=[]    

    #Global data axes 
    self.axis_x=[]

    #Global label axis y
    self.yticks = None

    # Drag time
    self.drag_time=0

    self.press = []

    self.drag_press = []

    self.xdrag=0
    self.ydrag=0

    #event data
    self.xdata=0
    self.ydata=0

    #event if we selecte edge
    self.node1=None
    self.node2=None          

    #cursor
    self.ly = self.ax.axvline(color='k')  # the vert line
    self.txt = self.ax.text(0.7, 0.9, '', transform=self.ax.transAxes) 

    #Node attibute popup
    self.popup = self.ax.text(0, 0, '', style='italic',bbox = {'facecolor':'y', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':10})

    #Edge attribute popup
    self.popupedge = self.ax.text(0, 0, '', style='italic',bbox = {'facecolor':'y', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':10})        


def draw_chronograph(self):
    #update graph
    self.G = self.controller.total_graph()

    #update data of nodecollection
    self.nodelist = self.controller.get_node_list()

    for i in range(len(self.nodelist)):
        self.event_name.append(self.nodelist[i].title)
        bottom = ((i-1)*0.5) + 1.0
        width = self.nodelist[i].end_time - self.nodelist[i].start_time
        left=self.nodelist[i].start_time
        height=0.3            

        rectangle = self.ax.bar(left,height,width,bottom)
        rectangle.bottom = bottom
        rectangle.i = i

        self.eventnode_with_rectangle.append([self.nodelist[i],rectangle])
        self.nodelist[i].pos=i
        self.datanode.append(self.nodelist[i].start_time)
        self.datanode.append(self.nodelist[i].end_time)

         #pos of i in the dictionnary


    taille=len(self.event_name)
    pos=arange(0.5,(taille+2)*0.5+0.5,0.5)

    self.yticks=yticks(pos,self.event_name)
    locsy,labelsy=self.yticks

    self.ax.set_yticks(pos)
    self.ax.set_yticklabels(labelsy, size='small')


    self.ax.axis('tight')

    self.ax.set_ylim(0, taille*0.5+0.5)

    self.ax.grid(color = 'g', linestyle = ':')

    font = font_manager.FontProperties(size='small')
    self.ax.legend(loc=1,prop=font)

    #format the x-axis
    self.ax.set_xlim(min(self.datanode), max(self.datanode))
    self.ax.xaxis.tick_top()

    # Finish up
    self.ax.invert_yaxis()
    self.fig.autofmt_xdate()

    #init cursor
    self.ly.set_xdata((min(self.datanode)+ max(self.datanode))/2)
    self.txt.set_text('y=%s' % ((min(self.datanode)+ max(self.datanode))/2))        

    self.canvas.draw()

def ChangeColor(self):
    def on_press(event):
        #update self.press
        self.press=[]

        x=event.xdata
        y=event.ydata
        self.press=[x,y]
        #print(event.button)
        if event.button == 1:
            for i,rectangle in self.eventnode_with_rectangle:
                if (i.start_time< self.press[0] <i.end_time) and ((i.pos-1)*0.5+1-0.15< self.press[1] <(i.pos-1)*0.5+1+0.15) :
                    rectangle=self.ax.barh(((i.pos-1)*0.5)+1.0, i.end_time - i.start_time, left=i.start_time, height=0.3, align='center', color='red', alpha = 0.75)

                rectangle=self.ax.barh(((i.pos-1)*0.5)+1.0, i.end_time - i.start_time, left=i.start_time, height=0.3, align='center', color='blue', alpha = 0.75)
            self.canvas.draw()
        else :
            return None

    def on_release(event):
        self.press = []
        self.canvas.draw()

    self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press)
    self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', on_release)  

def Detect(self):
    def event(event):
        actual_node = None
        x=event.xdata
        y=event.ydata
        for i,rectangle in self.eventnode_with_rectangle:
            if (i.start_time<x<i.end_time) and ((i.pos-1)*0.5+1-0.15<y<(i.pos-1)*0.5+1+0.15) :
                actual_node = i
                break 
        print("function drawchrono %s" %actual_node)
        return actual_node        


    self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', event) 

    import BasicModel as md
    import View as vw
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import forceatlas.forceatlas as nxfa2
    import undo
    import re
    import copy
```

class Controller:

```
def __init__(self, model):
    """
    Initialization: Gets the model

    :param model: Model class to use
    """
    # Loads the model
    self.model = model

if __name__ == '__main__':
     # Init Model
     MainModel = md.Model()

     # Init Controller
     MainController = Controller(MainModel)

     # Init View
     MainView = vw.View(MainController)

# Program Running.
```

Comment: I forget the last piece of my program. I have a controller which call my View.

Comment: This is quite a lot to take in, which makes it hard to answer the question. Could you edit it down a bit, maybe make a minimal example of the architecture that you've got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to add some pictures in order to better explain my problem.

[Canvas embedded in my GTK environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJR6s.png)

This is my GTK environment with the canvas (in white) using matplotlib to display things. My canvas is displayed with matplotlib. The canvas receives mouse events and it wil change the display of the canvas.

[Display of the popup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCXBl.png)
We can see a popup menu here. **So what is tricky here**, it is NO LONGER my canvas which receives the event, but it is actually **my GTK environment**.

So the problem is here :

I want to display different menu depending on the type of object that  I click on. I can do it easily if it is the canvas which receive event as I can directly calculate if the event is on a node or an edge, but if it is a GTK event, I can no longer detect if the event is on a node or on an edge.

So what should I do? **should I build a new class in order to connect GTK event and canvas event?**

Thanks